# How to mock AWS SDK2 (S3) in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, mocking, aws-sdk, stub

So I want to mock AWS SDK 2.x (only S3 service), so that test upload and download files to a bucket without a real AWS. I'm looking for a Java implementations.

I found a lot what implements (Adobe S3Mock ...etc), but all of them uses AWS SDK 1.x.

Comment: Well, you can wrap the library by calling it a connector or a service and do unit-test by mocking your own class. This will only work for simple unit-tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't re-implement the S3 API yourself. Instead, use one of the existing tools like [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), [MinIO](https://min.io), [OpenStack Swift](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/s3_compat.html) and others. They all provide S3-compatible API (though some dif ferences can be). The best one for tests is localstack, IMHO.It is available as a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/localstack/localstack), so you can use it locally or in your CI pipelines.

Not to the Java part of your question. If you are a lucky user of JUnit 5 I would recommend you to use [`aws-junit5`](https://madhead.me/posts/aws-junit5), a set of JUnit 5 extensions for AWS. And, yes, I am it's author. These extensions can be used to inject clients for AWS services provided by tools like localstack (actually, any AWS-compatible API is supported, including real AWS itself). Both AWS Java SDK v 2.x and v 1.x are supported. You can use `aws-junit5` to inject clients for S3, DynamoDB, Kinesis, SES, SNS and SQS.

Read more in the [user guide](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc), it even has a section about [CI configuration with GitHub](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc/#_bonus_ci_with_github).

Comment: How can I mock S3client without docker. I am writing unit test cases for S3. Can you post some example of mocking S3Client (aws sdk v2) in localStack or in MinIO.

Comment: just wants to test it like this:
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("foo", "bar")))
                .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:9192"))
                .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().buildWithDefaults(
                        AttributeMap.builder().put(TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE).build()
                ))
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

Since 2023-06-01 there is another option available, IF you are just using S3 in such simple ways, which can be expressed as file system manipulation:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3

Then write your program as if it would be just talking to a file system (via `java.nio.file.Path`s) and use https://github.com/google/jimfs to test it against an in-memory file system.

During actual use, you can switch between local file `Path.of(new URI("file://..."))` usage or S3 `Path.of(new URI("s3://<bucket>/..."))` usage.